# How to Add Workload Install Arguments for Visual Studio Chocolatey Package

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, chocolatey

I'm trying to create a chocolatey package for Visual Studio. I'm adding the package to a packages.config as [described here](https://docs.chocolatey.org/en-us/choco/commands/install#packages.config) so I can bulk install packages for quick setup. The problem I'm having is that the workloads I'm adding to the install arguments do not seem to work. It will install Visual Studio as expected but it will not install any of the workloads I've specified as defined [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/command-line-parameter-examples?view=vs-2019).

Here is my packages.config file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
    <package id="visualstudio2019pro.16.9.31205.134.nupkg" installArguments="--add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.ManagedDesktop`;includeRecommended --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetWeb`;includeRecommended`;includeOptional --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.Data`;includeRecommended --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.Azure --add Microsoft.Net.Component.4.8.TargetingPack" />
    <package id="docker-desktop.3.2.2.61853.nupkg" />
</packages>
```

I'm using powershell to run the command `choco install packages.config` but it's as if it does not recognize the install arguments. I was under the assumption that chocolatey would pass installArguments to the native installer. I've also tried adding single quotes nested in the double quotes but still the same result. Most examples I've see use commands with a slash in front and not double dashes(--) so I'm wondering if the double dashes(--) prefix to the add is confusing chocolatey since that's the syntax for the chocolatey commands. Maybe I need to escape those characters or something? I've tried using pure powershell to run the executable with the workloads and it will work as expected and install the workloads but I would like it to work using chocolatey.

Also here is a snippet of the chocolatey.log from my last install:

```
2021-09-24 16:54:07,593 6968 [DEBUG] - Running 'ChocolateyScriptRunner' for visualstudio2019pro v16.9.31205.134 with packageScript 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\visualstudio2019pro\tools\chocolateyinstall.ps1', packageFolder:'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\visualstudio2019pro', installArguments: '--add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.ManagedDesktop`;includeRecommended --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetWeb`;includeRecommended`;includeOptional --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.Data`;includeRecommended --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.Azure --add Microsoft.Net.Component.4.8.TargetingPack', packageParameters: '',
2021-09-24 16:54:07,608 6968 [DEBUG] - Running 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\visualstudio2019pro\tools\chocolateyinstall.ps1'
2021-09-24 16:54:07,744 6968 [DEBUG] - Running Install-ChocolateyInstallPackage -silentArgs '--quiet' -packageName 'visualstudio2019pro' -fileType 'EXE' -validExitCodes '0 3010 1641' -file 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\visualstudio2019pro\tools\vs_professional__1016528693.1618336841.exe' 
2021-09-24 16:54:07,764 6968 [DEBUG] - Running Get-ProcessorBits -compare '32' 
2021-09-24 16:54:07,819 6968 [INFO ] - Installing visualstudio2019pro...
2021-09-24 16:54:07,995 6968 [DEBUG] - Running Start-ChocolateyProcessAsAdmin -validExitCodes '0 3010 1641' -workingDirectory 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\visualstudio2019pro\tools' -statements '--quiet ' -exeToRun 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\visualstudio2019pro\tools\vs_professional__1016528693.1618336841.exe' 
2021-09-24 16:54:07,995 6968 [DEBUG] - Unable to use current location for Working Directory. Using Cache Location instead.
2021-09-24 16:54:08,045 6968 [DEBUG] - Test-ProcessAdminRights: returning True
2021-09-24 16:54:08,046 6968 [DEBUG] - Elevating permissions and running ["C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\visualstudio2019pro\tools\vs_professional__1016528693.1618336841.exe" --quiet ]. This may take a while, depending on the statements.
2021-09-24 16:54:11,753 6968 [INFO ] - VERBOSE: Preparing: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\chocolatey\1be5a6879ddf2fc2f2528584\vs_bootstrapper_d15\HelpFile\1028\help.html...
2021-09-24 16:54:11,753 6968 [INFO ] - VERBOSE: Preparing: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\chocolatey\1be5a6879ddf2fc2f2528584\vs_bootstrapper_d15\HelpFile\2052\help.html...
2021-09-24 16:54:11,753 6968 [INFO ] - VERBOSE: 
2021-09-24 16:54:11,753 6968 [INFO ] - VERBOSE: Preparing: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\chocolatey\1be5a6879ddf2fc2f2528584\vs_bootstrapper_d15\HelpFile\1029\help.html...
2021-09-24 16:54:11,753 6968 [INFO ] - VERBOSE: 
2021-09-24 16:54:11,753 6968 [INFO ] - VERBOSE: Preparing: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\chocolatey\1be5a6879ddf2fc2f2528584\vs_bootstrapper_d15\HelpFile\1042\help.html...
2021-09-24 16:54:11,753 6968 [INFO ] - VERBOSE: 
2021-09-24 16:54:11,753 6968 [INFO ] - VERBOSE: Preparing: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\chocolatey\1be5a6879ddf2fc2f2528584\vs_bootstrapper_d15\HelpFile\1036\help.html...
2021-09-24 16:54:11,799 6968 [INFO ] - VERBOSE: 
2021-09-24 16:54:11,799 6968 [INFO ] - VERBOSE: Preparing: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\chocolatey\1be5a6879ddf2fc2f2528584\vs_bootstrapper_d15\HelpFile\3082\help.html...
2021-09-24 16:54:11,805 6968 [INFO ] - VERBOSE: 
2021-09-24 16:54:11,805 6968 [INFO ] - VERBOSE: Preparing: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\chocolatey\1be5a6879ddf2fc2f2528584\vs_bootstrapper_d15\HelpFile\1040\help.html...
2021-09-24 16:54:11,805 6968 [INFO ] - VERBOSE: 
2021-09-24 16:54:11,805 6968 [INFO ] - VERBOSE: Preparing: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\chocolatey\1be5a6879ddf2fc2f2528584\vs_bootstrapper_d15\HelpFile\1031\help.html...
2021-09-24 16:54:11,805 6968 [INFO ] - VERBOSE: 
2021-09-24 16:54:11,805 6968 [INFO ] - VERBOSE: Preparing: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\chocolatey\1be5a6879ddf2fc2f2528584\vs_bootstrapper_d15\HelpFile\1045\help.html...
2021-09-24 16:54:11,805 6968 [INFO ] - VERBOSE: 
2021-09-24 16:54:11,805 6968 [INFO ] - VERBOSE: Preparing: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\chocolatey\1be5a6879ddf2fc2f2528584\vs_bootstrapper_d15\HelpFile\1041\help.html...
2021-09-24 16:54:11,805 6968 [INFO ] - VERBOSE: 
2021-09-24 16:54:11,805 6968 [INFO ] - VERBOSE: Preparing: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\chocolatey\1be5a6879ddf2fc2f2528584\vs_bootstrapper_d15\HelpFile\1055\help.html...
2021-09-24 16:54:11,805 6968 [INFO ] - VERBOSE: 
2021-09-24 16:54:11,805 6968 [INFO ] - VERBOSE: Preparing: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\chocolatey\1be5a6879ddf2fc2f2528584\vs_bootstrapper_d15\HelpFile\1046\help.html...
2021-09-24 16:54:11,805 6968 [INFO ] - VERBOSE: 
2021-09-24 16:54:11,805 6968 [INFO ] - VERBOSE: Preparing: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\chocolatey\1be5a6879ddf2fc2f2528584\vs_bootstrapper_d15\HelpFile\1049\help.html...
2021-09-24 16:54:11,805 6968 [INFO ] - VERBOSE: 
2021-09-24 16:54:11,805 6968 [INFO ] - VERBOSE: Preparing: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\chocolatey\1be5a6879ddf2fc2f2528584\vs_bootstrapper_d15\HelpFile\1033\help.html...
2021-09-24 16:54:11,805 6968 [INFO ] - VERBOSE: 
2021-09-24 16:54:11,805 6968 [INFO ] - VERBOSE: Preparing: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\chocolatey\1be5a6879ddf2fc2f2528584\vs_bootstrapper_d15\vs_setup_bootstrapper.exe...
2021-09-24 16:54:11,805 6968 [INFO ] - VERBOSE: 
2021-09-24 16:54:11,805 6968 [INFO ] - VERBOSE: Preparing: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\chocolatey\1be5a6879ddf2fc2f2528584\vs_bootstrapper_d15\Microsoft.C2RSignatureReader.Interop.dll...
2021-09-24 16:54:11,805 6968 [INFO ] - VERBOSE: 
2021-09-24 16:54:11,831 6968 [INFO ] - VERBOSE: Preparing: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\chocolatey\1be5a6879ddf2fc2f2528584\vs_bootstrapper_d15\Microsoft.C2RSignatureReader.Native.dll...
2021-09-24 16:54:11,831 6968 [INFO ] - VERBOSE: 
2021-09-24 16:54:11,831 6968 [INFO ] - VERBOSE: Preparing: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\chocolatey\1be5a6879ddf2fc2f2528584\vs_bootstrapper_d15\Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventSource.dll...
2021-09-24 16:54:11,834 6968 [INFO ] - VERBOSE: 
2021-09-24 16:54:11,834 6968 [INFO ] - VERBOSE: Preparing: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\chocolatey\1be5a6879ddf2fc2f2528584\vs_bootstrapper_d15\Microsoft.VisualStudio.RemoteControl.dll...
2021-09-24 16:54:11,834 6968 [INFO ] - VERBOSE: 
2021-09-24 16:54:11,834 6968 [INFO ] - VERBOSE: Preparing: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\chocolatey\1be5a6879ddf2fc2f2528584\vs_bootstrapper_d15\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Common.dll...
2021-09-24 16:54:11,834 6968 [INFO ] - VERBOSE: 
2021-09-24 16:54:11,834 6968 [INFO ] - VERBOSE: Preparing: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\chocolatey\1be5a6879ddf2fc2f2528584\vs_bootstrapper_d15\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.dll...
2021-09-24 16:54:11,834 6968 [INFO ] - VERBOSE: 
2021-09-24 16:54:11,834 6968 [INFO ] - VERBOSE: Preparing: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\chocolatey\1be5a6879ddf2fc2f2528584\vs_bootstrapper_d15\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Download.dll...
2021-09-24 16:54:11,834 6968 [INFO ] - VERBOSE: 
2021-09-24 16:54:11,834 6968 [INFO ] - VERBOSE: Preparing: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\chocolatey\1be5a6879ddf2fc2f2528584\vs_bootstrapper_d15\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Telemetry.dll...
2021-09-24 16:54:11,834 6968 [INFO ] - VERBOSE: 
2021-09-24 16:54:11,834 6968 [INFO ] - VERBOSE: Preparing: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\chocolatey\1be5a6879ddf2fc2f2528584\vs_bootstrapper_d15\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Utilities.Internal.dll...
2021-09-24 16:54:11,834 6968 [INFO ] - VERBOSE: 
2021-09-24 16:54:11,834 6968 [INFO ] - VERBOSE: Preparing: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\chocolatey\1be5a6879ddf2fc2f2528584\vs_bootstrapper_d15\Newtonsoft.Json.dll...
2021-09-24 16:54:11,834 6968 [INFO ] - VERBOSE: 
2021-09-24 16:54:11,834 6968 [INFO ] - VERBOSE: Preparing: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\chocolatey\1be5a6879ddf2fc2f2528584\vs_bootstrapper_d15\zh-Hant\vs_setup_bootstrapper.resources.dll...
2021-09-24 16:54:11,834 6968 [INFO ] - VERBOSE: 
2021-09-24 16:54:11,834 6968 [INFO ] - VERBOSE: Preparing: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\chocolatey\1be5a6879ddf2fc2f2528584\vs_bootstrapper_d15\pl\vs_setup_bootstrapper.resources.dll...
2021-09-24 16:54:11,858 6968 [INFO ] - VERBOSE: 
2021-09-24 16:54:11,858 6968 [INFO ] - VERBOSE: Preparing: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\chocolatey\1be5a6879ddf2fc2f2528584\vs_bootstrapper_d15\fr\vs_setup_bootstrapper.resources.dll...
2021-09-24 16:54:11,861 6968 [INFO ] - VERBOSE: 
2021-09-24 16:54:11,861 6968 [INFO ] - VERBOSE: Preparing: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\chocolatey\1be5a6879ddf2fc2f2528584\vs_bootstrapper_d15\es\vs_setup_bootstrapper.resources.dll...
2021-09-24 16:54:11,861 6968 [INFO ] - VERBOSE: 
2021-09-24 16:54:11,861 6968 [INFO ] - VERBOSE: Preparing: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\chocolatey\1be5a6879ddf2fc2f2528584\vs_bootstrapper_d15\tr\vs_setup_bootstrapper.resources.dll...
2021-09-24 16:54:11,861 6968 [INFO ] - VERBOSE: 
2021-09-24 16:54:11,861 6968 [INFO ] - VERBOSE: 
2021-09-24 16:54:11,861 6968 [INFO ] - VERBOSE: Preparing: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\chocolatey\1be5a6879ddf2fc2f2528584\vs_bootstrapper_d15\it\vs_setup_bootstrapper.resources.dll...
2021-09-24 16:54:11,861 6968 [INFO ] - VERBOSE: 
2021-09-24 16:54:11,861 6968 [INFO ] - VERBOSE: Preparing: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\chocolatey\1be5a6879ddf2fc2f2528584\vs_bootstrapper_d15\pt-BR\vs_setup_bootstrapper.resources.dll...
2021-09-24 16:54:11,861 6968 [INFO ] - VERBOSE: 
2021-09-24 16:54:11,861 6968 [INFO ] - VERBOSE: Preparing: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\chocolatey\1be5a6879ddf2fc2f2528584\vs_bootstrapper_d15\de\vs_setup_bootstrapper.resources.dll...
2021-09-24 16:54:11,861 6968 [INFO ] - VERBOSE: 
2021-09-24 16:54:11,861 6968 [INFO ] - VERBOSE: Preparing: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\chocolatey\1be5a6879ddf2fc2f2528584\vs_bootstrapper_d15\ru\vs_setup_bootstrapper.resources.dll...
2021-09-24 16:54:11,861 6968 [INFO ] - VERBOSE: 
2021-09-24 16:54:11,861 6968 [INFO ] - VERBOSE: Preparing: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\chocolatey\1be5a6879ddf2fc2f2528584\vs_bootstrapper_d15\cs\vs_setup_bootstrapper.resources.dll...
2021-09-24 16:54:11,861 6968 [INFO ] - VERBOSE: 
2021-09-24 16:54:11,861 6968 [INFO ] - VERBOSE: Preparing: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\chocolatey\1be5a6879ddf2fc2f2528584\vs_bootstrapper_d15\ko\vs_setup_bootstrapper.resources.dll...
2021-09-24 16:54:11,861 6968 [INFO ] - VERBOSE: 
2021-09-24 16:54:11,861 6968 [INFO ] - VERBOSE: Preparing: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\chocolatey\1be5a6879ddf2fc2f2528584\vs_bootstrapper_d15\zh-Hans\vs_setup_bootstrapper.resources.dll...
2021-09-24 16:54:11,861 6968 [INFO ] - VERBOSE: 
2021-09-24 16:54:11,880 6968 [INFO ] - VERBOSE: Preparing: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\chocolatey\1be5a6879ddf2fc2f2528584\vs_bootstrapper_d15\ja\vs_setup_bootstrapper.resources.dll...
2021-09-24 16:54:11,880 6968 [INFO ] - VERBOSE: 
2021-09-24 16:54:11,880 6968 [INFO ] - VERBOSE: Preparing: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\chocolatey\1be5a6879ddf2fc2f2528584\vs_bootstrapper_d15\vs_setup_bootstrapper.config...
2021-09-24 16:54:11,880 6968 [INFO ] - VERBOSE: 
2021-09-24 16:54:11,880 6968 [INFO ] - VERBOSE: Preparing: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\chocolatey\1be5a6879ddf2fc2f2528584\vs_bootstrapper_d15\vs_setup_bootstrapper.exe.config...
2021-09-24 16:54:11,880 6968 [INFO ] - VERBOSE: 
2021-09-24 16:54:11,880 6968 [INFO ] - VERBOSE: Preparing: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\chocolatey\1be5a6879ddf2fc2f2528584\vs_bootstrapper_d15\detection.json...
2021-09-24 16:54:11,887 6968 [INFO ] - VERBOSE: 
2021-09-24 16:54:11,888 6968 [INFO ] - VERBOSE: Preparing: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\chocolatey\1be5a6879ddf2fc2f2528584\vs_bootstrapper_d15\vs_setup_bootstrapper.json...
2021-09-24 16:54:11,888 6968 [INFO ] - VERBOSE: 
2021-09-24 16:54:11,917 6968 [DEBUG] - Command ["C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\visualstudio2019pro\tools\vs_professional__1016528693.1618336841.exe" --quiet ] exited with '0'.
2021-09-24 16:54:11,917 6968 [DEBUG] - Finishing 'Start-ChocolateyProcessAsAdmin'
2021-09-24 16:54:11,932 6968 [INFO ] - visualstudio2019pro has been installed.
2021-09-24 16:54:11,944 6968 [DEBUG] - ----------------------------------------------------------------------
2021-09-24 16:54:12,001 6968 [DEBUG] - Built-in PowerShell host called with ['[System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = '';[System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = ''; & import-module -name 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\helpers\chocolateyInstaller.psm1'; & 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\helpers\chocolateyScriptRunner.ps1' -packageScript 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\visualstudio2019pro\tools\chocolateyinstall.ps1' -installArguments '--add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.ManagedDesktop`;includeRecommended --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetWeb`;includeRecommended`;includeOptional --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.Data`;includeRecommended --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.Azure --add Microsoft.Net.Component.4.8.TargetingPack' -packageParameters '''] exited with '0'.
2021-09-24 16:54:12,001 6968 [DEBUG] - Calling command ['"C:\Windows\System32\shutdown.exe" /a']
2021-09-24 16:54:12,135 6968 [DEBUG] - Command ['"C:\Windows\System32\shutdown.exe" /a'] exited with '1116'
2021-09-24 16:54:12,234 6968 [DEBUG] - Capturing package files in 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\visualstudio2019pro'
2021-09-24 16:54:12,234 6968 [DEBUG] -  Found 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\visualstudio2019pro\visualstudio2019pro.nupkg'
  with checksum '80F5D57F5F6AB598FA2918BCC159915E'
2021-09-24 16:54:12,234 6968 [DEBUG] -  Found 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\visualstudio2019pro\visualstudio2019pro.nuspec'
  with checksum '7B3D802C120A1ECFF143C7F170555C63'
2021-09-24 16:54:12,234 6968 [DEBUG] -  Found 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\visualstudio2019pro\tools\chocolateybeforemodify.ps1'
  with checksum '82C5D8514A337F56053E803CC0C329F6'
2021-09-24 16:54:12,234 6968 [DEBUG] -  Found 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\visualstudio2019pro\tools\chocolateyinstall.ps1'
  with checksum '39B967B5CD0D8ADA61B74B04438F99FF'
2021-09-24 16:54:12,234 6968 [DEBUG] -  Found 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\visualstudio2019pro\tools\chocolateyuninstall.ps1'
  with checksum '42698D995D08EC5BCEAB3100CCAD0A98'
2021-09-24 16:54:12,249 6968 [DEBUG] -  Found 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\visualstudio2019pro\tools\LICENSE.txt'
  with checksum 'C0A6C63571D90B7DE831EF3FE1C43162'
2021-09-24 16:54:12,249 6968 [DEBUG] -  Found 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\visualstudio2019pro\tools\VERIFICATION.txt'
  with checksum 'B227967C2E978A3D3599910E5F79FFC5'
2021-09-24 16:54:12,259 6968 [DEBUG] -  Found 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\visualstudio2019pro\tools\vs_professional__1016528693.1618336841.exe'
  with checksum '1CDEADB8A673A3CABEED2D6C1A7392BF'
2021-09-24 16:54:12,259 6968 [DEBUG] -  Found 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\visualstudio2019pro\tools\vs_professional__1016528693.1618336841.exe.ignore'
  with checksum 'BEA07E6D2B8DCE396FE21BAA61B34956'
2021-09-24 16:54:12,305 6968 [DEBUG] - Attempting to delete file "C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\.chocolatey\visualstudio2019pro.16.9.31205.134\.arguments".
2021-09-24 16:54:12,305 6968 [DEBUG] - Attempting to delete file "C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\.chocolatey\visualstudio2019pro.16.9.31205.134\.extra".
2021-09-24 16:54:12,305 6968 [DEBUG] - Attempting to delete file "C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\.chocolatey\visualstudio2019pro.16.9.31205.134\.version".
2021-09-24 16:54:12,319 6968 [DEBUG] - Attempting to delete file "C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\.chocolatey\visualstudio2019pro.16.9.31205.134\.sxs".
2021-09-24 16:54:12,319 6968 [DEBUG] - Attempting to delete file "C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\.chocolatey\visualstudio2019pro.16.9.31205.134\.pin".
2021-09-24 16:54:12,319 6968 [DEBUG] - Sending message 'HandlePackageResultCompletedMessage' out if there are subscribers...
2021-09-24 16:54:12,319 6968 [DEBUG] - Attempting to delete file "C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\visualstudio2019pro\.chocolateyPending".
2021-09-24 16:54:12,319 6968 [INFO ] -  The install of visualstudio2019pro was successful.
2021-09-24 16:54:12,319 6968 [INFO ] -   Software installed as 'EXE', install location is likely default.
2021-09-24 16:54:12,342 6968 [DEBUG] - Updating source and package name to handle *.nupkg or *.nuspec file.
2021-09-24 16:54:12,374 6968 [WARN ] - docker-desktop v3.2.2.61853 already installed.
 Use --force to reinstall, specify a version to install, or try upgrade.
2021-09-24 16:54:12,401 6968 [WARN ] - 
Chocolatey installed 1/2 packages. 
 See the log for details (C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\logs\chocolatey.log).
2021-09-24 16:54:12,426 6968 [INFO ] - 
2021-09-24 16:54:12,426 6968 [WARN ] - Warnings:
2021-09-24 16:54:12,440 6968 [WARN ] -  - docker-desktop - docker-desktop v3.2.2.61853 already installed.
 Use --force to reinstall, specify a version to install, or try upgrade.
2021-09-24 16:54:12,440 6968 [DEBUG] - Sending message 'PostRunMessage' out if there are subscribers...
2021-09-24 16:54:12,474 6968 [DEBUG] - Exiting with 0
```

Comment: I could not find a link to the packages.config schema for chocolatey. But in your case you might try seeing if `overrideArguments` works in place of `installArguments`, as `--install-arguments` *adds* arguments to what is defined for `-SilentArgs` within the package; I think it is here you might be hitting a conflict. From the CLI `--override-arguments/-o` will totally replace the package defined args for a silent install. Note that if this works you will need to provide *all* of the arguments required for a silent install, as `-o` will completely replace the args defined in the package.

Comment: I'm hesitant to provide this as an answer because while `overrideArguments` would be the *logical* name for this in the `packages.config` schema, I do not know if that is the name or if the schema supports providing override arguments in this way. Please comment back if this works for you or not.

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work for me. Adding overrideArguments to the packages.config did not seem to have an affect. I ended up just including the install arguments along with the silentArgs in the chocolateyInstall.ps1 and repackaged it. This worked but is not very convenient as I will need to repackage it anytime workloads change. But I will deal with that for now. I just wish there was better documentation on the packages.config syntax.

Comment: Darn. I still think there's got to be a way for it though. I hate that the chocolatey specific schemas are *not documented* ([this is not a schema definition](https://docs.chocolatey.org/en-us/choco/commands/install#packages.config)) which is antithesis to the generally well-kept documentation of Chocolatey on the whole.

Comment: You might do well to ask about this on [Github](https://github.com/chocolatey/choco/issues), and if `overrideArguments` is truly not supported, I think this feature would probably be met with enthusiasm IMO. Without it, it limits the usefulness of `choco install packages.config` when packages were installed with `-o` specified.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `packageParameters` attribute instead of `installArguments`.

I did not include these bits. So, you could try leaving them off if you still have problems.

```
`;includeRecommended`;includeOptional
```

This the the packages.config file that I used to install both workloads and individual components.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <!-- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/workload-component-id-vs-enterprise?view=vs-2022&preserve-view=true -->
  <package id="visualstudio2022enterprise" packageParameters="--add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.ManagedDesktop --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetWeb --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.Data --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.Node --add Microsoft.NetCore.Component.Runtime.3.1 --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Workflow"/>
</packages>
```

This was the command that I used to install the packages within the `packages.config` file.

```
Set-Location $pathToFolderThatContainsPackagesConfig;
choco install packages.config
```